# location manager is not on main thread after segue?

Tags: ios, swift, mkmapview, cllocationmanager

I have a serious problem about use location manage and mapview.

I create a app simple show where the location I am now, it runs ok when only one viewcontroller, but after I added a viewController and segue, and after segue first viewController to map viewController, it has some error message:

> location manager (0x101f3d870) was created on a dispatch queue executing on a thread other than the main thread

after that, the App crash with this error message :

> MKMapView must be initialized on the main thread

But I really move the code into the main thread, and it does ok before I added first viewcontroller and segue!!!  The code at below:

```
import UIKit
import MapKit
import CoreLocation

class Map_ViewController: UIViewController,MKMapViewDelegate,CLLocationManagerDelegate,UISearchBarDelegate {

    @IBOutlet weak var mapView: MKMapView!

    var cloaction = CLLocationManager()
    var span = MKCoordinateSpan(latitudeDelta: 0.01, longitudeDelta: 0.01)
    var currentLat : Double = 0
    var currentLon : Double = 0

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

    }

    override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        // Start get the location on viewWillAppear
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
            self.mapView.delegate = self
            self.mapView.showsScale = true

            self.mapView.showsPointsOfInterest = true
            self.mapView.showsUserLocation = true

            self.cloaction.requestAlwaysAuthorization()
            self.cloaction.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()

            if CLLocationManager.locationServicesEnabled() {
                self.cloaction.delegate = self
                self.cloaction.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest
                self.cloaction.startUpdatingLocation()
            }

            setCenter()
        }
    }

    func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation]) {

        if let location = locations.last {
            mapView.region.center = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: location.coordinate.latitude, longitude: location.coordinate.longitude)
            mapView.setRegion(mapView.region, animated: false)
        }
    }

    func setCenter() {
        let center = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: mapView.userLocation.coordinate.latitude, longitude: mapView.userLocation.coordinate.longitude)
        mapView.region.center = center
        mapView.region.span = span
        mapView.setRegion(mapView.region, animated: true)
    }

}
```

The segue in the main viewController :

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "goToMap", sender: nil)

}
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {

    print("goToMapViewController")

}
```

Comment: may be not related to actual issue, but you are missing `super.viewWillAppear`

Comment: The problem is likely in the view controller that presented this one. Likely, you didn’t initiate that on the main thread. And once you do that, you can get rid of the `DispatchQueue.main.async { ... }` in this view controller.

Comment: Yes, please edit your question to show how you initiate the segue in the previous view controller.

Comment: Thank you a lot, I added the  segue in the previous view controller. But I still confuse, why after I use  DispatchQueue.main.async { ... }, the same error message still pop up?

Comment: Don't perform segues in `viewDidLoad`.  if you want to segue straight to another view controller, perform the segue in `viewDidAppear`

Comment: Also, if you want to track the user's location, you can just enable user location tracking on the map view; There is no need to implement `didUpdateLocations` and do it yourself.

Comment: Oh ya, you are right, it's works, thank you. This issue is so unusual and hard to me. Thanks again.